# get the key of a json array using python 3

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

I am trying to get the value of a key in my json Array.

Here is the structure of my Json  the output of my variable :

```
databill.append({
            "bloc":BlocNum,
            "subBlocNum":subBlocNum, 
            "detection":TextExtraction,       
        })    
print(databill)


[{'bloc': 1, 'subBlocNum': 0, 'detection': 'Nr TraNSaCt. A. 0N'},
 {'bloc': 1, 'subBlocNum': 1, 'detection': '17S'},
 {'bloc': 2, 'subBlocNum': 2, 'detection': 'S0LDE'},
 {'bloc': 2, 'subBlocNum': 3, 'detection': '35. 34'},
 {'bloc': 3, 'subBlocNum': 4, 'detection': 'ANCIEN S0LDE .'},
 {'bloc': 3, 'subBlocNum': 5, 'detection': '41. 73'}]
```

I would Like to get the value of the key "detection" for the bloc 3 and subBlocNum:5

Here the value would be 41.73

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I Have the json part cause the code is too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing if there can be more than one JSON object with the desired values in the list then I would use a list comprehension like so:

```
databill = [{'bloc': 1, 'subBlocNum': 0, 'detection': 'Nr TraNSaCt. A. 0N'},
 {'bloc': 1, 'subBlocNum': 1, 'detection': '17S'},
 {'bloc': 2, 'subBlocNum': 2, 'detection': 'S0LDE'},
 {'bloc': 2, 'subBlocNum': 3, 'detection': '35. 34'},
 {'bloc': 3, 'subBlocNum': 4, 'detection': 'ANCIEN S0LDE .'},
 {'bloc': 3, 'subBlocNum': 5, 'detection': '41. 73'}]

[d['detection'] for d in databill if d['bloc']==3 and d['subBlocNum']==5]

['41.73']
```